# Can a batsman use a reverse grip?

Tags: rules, cricket

My 10 year old son is right handed batsman however has a left handed batsman's grip i.e. left hand down and right hand on top on the grip. Is that allowed in international cricket as per ICC rules?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this is "yes, this is allowed". There's nothing in the Laws of the Game which specify how the bat should be held.